# Basic form validation mechanism PHP

Tags: php, arrays, forms, validation

I'm trying to set up simple example for form validation, whether field is empty or not. If field is not empty action redirect me to page ok.php and if not back to formvalidation.php. and change css of the field. I have problem with returning error array back to formvalidation.php and testing it to change css for input field. What am I doing wrong?

formvalidation.php

```
<?php require("includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php   
    global $errors;
?>

<form action="posting.php" method="p">
    <ul>
        <li id="field">
            <label for="field">Contact person </label>
            <input 
            <?php
            if (empty($errors)) {
                echo "style=\"background-color:   #ECECEC;\"";
            } else {
                if (in_array("field", $errors)) {
                    echo "style=\"background-color: red;\"";}
                } else {
                    echo "style=\"background-color:       #ECECEC;\"";
                }
            }
            ?> 
            type="text" name="field"/>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit"  name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

action.php

```
<?php require("includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php
    $errors = form_validation ();

    if (!empty($errors)) {
        redirect_to("formvalidation.php");
    } else {
        redirect_to("ok.php");
    }
?>
```

function

```
<?php
function form_validation () {

    $errors = array ();

    $required_fields = array('field');
    foreach($required_fields as $fieldname) {
        if (!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) || empty($_POST[$fieldname])) {
            $errors[] = $fieldname;
        }
    }

    return $errors;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After redirect `$error` variable is empty use `$_SESSION`

```
<?php
    $_SESSION['error']=form_validation ();

    if (!empty($_SESSION['error'])) {
        redirect_to("formvalidation.php");
    } else {redirect_to("ok.php");}
?>
```

And in formvalidation.php

```
$error=$_SESSION['error'];
unset($_SESSION['error']);
```

don't forget to ensure that `session_start()` is on the top of your code

Comment: I have changed action code with yours, and I have put session_start() at the top of formvalidation.php, right? But this does not change css, since I think it returns empty $error = $_SESSION['error']. Field should be colored red when is posted empty, but it remains gray.

Comment: print_r($_SESSION['error']); and post output. session must starts in action.php too

Comment: It outputs what it should Array ( [0] => field ) after posting. Could be the problem with storing it into $error. How to check whats in variable, because echo $error gives nothing? Also, should I unset($_SESSION['error']); at the bottom of the page?

Comment: you can check whats in variable. in action.php  after  `$_SESSION['error']=form_validation ();`  write `print_r($_SESSION['error']); exit;`

Comment: No, I thought on variable that I declare in formvalidation.php $error = $_SESSION['error']. $_SESSION['error'] is transferd ok, and on this page print_r($_SESSION['error']) outputs Array ( [0] => field ) after posting

Comment: you have error `echo "style=\"background-color: red;\"";}` here delete `}`

Comment: That was mistype, i corrected that way before. This is what I have put on formvalidation.php. and it gives me error "array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given"    $errors = $_SESSION['errors'];
 print_r($_SESSION['error']);
 if(array_key_exists (0,$errors)) {echo "yes";} else {echo "no";}

Comment: It's not ok, because it says that $errors = $_SESSION['error'] variable which I declare at the beginning of formvalidation.php is not an array even if print_r($_SESSION['error']) outputs Array ( [0] => field ).

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look at this tutorial: http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-validation.html. It's implemented more object-oriented.